# Expection Handling for Menu System

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement

I am currently building a program in Java for college. Part of this is to build a menu system. The tutor would like exception handling on the menu. It is a simple menu with no user interface.

The menu is a switch statement with the user entering which option they would like;

1. Option One
2. Option Two
3. Option Three

What the tutor would like is a try catch method, one so that the user can enter either the number 1 or enter "One" and the system doesn't crash.

I have read countless articles online but I either can't find help on this or it goes right over my head. Any help with this would be fantastic.

EDIT:
So it is a first year class, he just wants the functionality down and we can do a run through for him. I can get the code now. There is firstly the PremiumAccount class, then the main menu is in the program class calling each of the methods. You can find the menu below here, I can also put up the PremiumAccount class if needed.

do{

```
        System.out.println("Premium Phone!");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please select the option for which you would like to do!");
        System.out.println("1. Make a Call");
        System.out.println("2. Send a Text");
        System.out.println("3. Top Up");
        System.out.println("4. Display your details");
        System.out.println("5. Get your balance");
        System.out.println("6. Get your minutes used");
        System.out.println("7. Get your texts sent");
        System.out.println("8. Update the Call Costs");
        System.out.println("9. Update the Text Costs");
        System.out.println("10. Update the discount rate");
        System.out.println("11. Exit");
        intMenuChoice = numInput.nextInt(); //user input menu choice

        switch(intMenuChoice)
        {
            case 1: System.out.print("Please enter the amount length of the call in minutes: ");
                    intMinutesUsed = numInput.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(pre123.makeCall(intMinutesUsed));
                    System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 2: System.out.print("Please enter the amount of characters used in the text: "); 
                    intCharactersUsed = numInput.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(pre123.sendText(intCharactersUsed));
                    System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 3: System.out.print("Please enter the amount you would like to Top Up: ");
                    dblTopUp = numInput.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println(pre123.topUp(dblTopUp));
                    System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 4: System.out.println("***Account Details***");
                    pre123.displayAccountDetails();
                    System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 5: System.out.println("Account Balance: £" +df.format(pre123.getBalance()));
                    System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 6: System.out.println("Minutes Used: " +pre123.getMinutes());
                    System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 7: System.out.println("Texts Used: " +pre123.getTexts());
                    System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 8: System.out.print("Please enter the new Cost of a Call: ");
                    newCallCost = numInput.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println(pre123.updateCallCost(newCallCost));
                    System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 9: System.out.println("Please enter the next Cost of a Text: ");
                    newTextCost = numInput.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println(pre123.updateTextCost(newTextCost));
                    System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 10: System.out.println("Please enter the new rate of Discount");
                     newDiscount = numInput.nextDouble();
                     System.out.println(pre123.setNewDiscount(newDiscount));
                     System.out.println("");
                break;
            case 11: System.out.println("Have a nice Day!");
                     menuStatus = 1;
                break;

            default: System.out.println("Please select a number between 1 - 11");

        }//end switch statement


    }while(menuStatus == 0);//end do while
```

We would just need as I said for the user to be able to enter in which they want but have a try catch so they can enter "1" or "one" and the system doesn't crash if they type it

Thanks a lot in advance
Conor

Comment: Post the code with the question of whatever you have tried up until now.

Comment: A menu with no user interface? Who is supposed to use it then?

Comment: Main post edited with code thanks!

Comment: Really puzzling, that your tutor wants to teach you to abuse exceptions!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Integer.parseInt()` and catch the `NumberFormatException` and then go ahead an check the `String`

**AFTER EDIT**

Instead of `intMenuChoice = numInput.nextInt();` you could use `String input = numInput.nextLine();` Then add the following

```
try{
   intMenuChoice = Integer.parseInt(input);
}catch (NumberFormatException e){
   switch(input.toLowerCase()){
      case "one":
         intMenuChoice = 1;
         break;
      ......//So on

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";

    System.out.print("Enter the menu item: "); 
    input = scan.NextLine();

    try{
        if(input.equals("One") || input.equals("1"))
            doOptionOne();
        else
            throw new Exception("The menu option is not 1 or One"); //throws exception if the choice is not valid 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); //print the exception message
    }
}
```